# Can you still use Weapon Finesse or Impoved Critical if you use Magus' Eldritch Athame to change a weapon to a different one?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

> **Edritch Athame (Su)**
>
> Benefit: The magus can spend 1 point from her arcane pool as a
>   swift action to transforms her weapon into a weapon of pure magical
>   energy for 1 minute per magus class level. She can cause it to adopt a
>   new form suitable to the opponent at hand. The weapon retains any
>   magical qualities it had in its normal form. The magus can choose to
>   return it to its normal form before that time. The weapon can become
>   any weapon that is the same size or one category larger or smaller
>   than its base form. The magus gains proficiency with that specific
>   weapon during that time. A magus can transform the weapon into a
>   ranged weapon, but she must supply ammunition as normal.

Can you still use Weapon Finesse or Impoved Critical  if you use Magus' Eldritch Athame to change a weapon to a different one?

Answer (score 4):

A weapon affected by the eldritch athame ability becomes the new weapon, and nothing denies you the use of Weapon Finesse or Improved Critical with the new weapon except the new weapon itself. Transforming a rapier into a greatsword, for instance, renders the effect of Weapon Finesse useless.

Improved Critical is a different matter. Its wording suggests it's a feat that only applies to a chosen weapon, and it doesn't ever explain that, so ask your GM if 'chosen weapon' means 'the weapon I've had since my 11th birthday, used to slay a dozen hobgoblins' rather than 'longspears' or 'the longspear I've had since my 11th etc.'.

Comment: FWIW, every game I've been in has interpreted "chosen weapon" to mean "longspears".

Comment: @Powerdork Improved Critical actually never even tells you to choose or select a weapon, so technically doesn't work at all...and yet most players understand what was intended. The Special text also uses 'weapon type' rather than weapon...